# Infinite reflected ray on an ellipse?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

The following property of an ellipse was told to me by my teachers but was never proved:

> "Let E be an ellipse. Let a focal ray R be reflected within the ellipse E. Ultimately after 'infinite reflections', it will travel along the major axis of E."

I am not able to prove this property - mainly because I can't think of any other approach other than the brute force approach to solving it - in which the equations get very tedious.

**Brute force approach:**
Let $$ E: \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1,  a > b > 0$$. Let the original ray be $R_0$: $y - b\sin\phi_0 = m_0(x - a\cos\phi_0)$ which is reflected at $P(\phi_0)$ with a slope of $m_0$. [$\phi_0$ is the eccentric angle of the point P on the ellipse.] The idea was to get the sequences $(\phi_n)$ and $m_n$ where $(\phi_n)$ and $m_n$ are the eccentric angle and slope of the ray after the $n^{th}$ reflection; and then show that $m_n \rightarrow 0$. However the problem is that the equations for $m_1$ and $\phi_1$ itself get so tedious, it is very difficult to solve for $m_n$.

How can I prove the property?

Comment: So let us take a circle, this is my favorite ellipse, then inside of it, inscribed in it a square. (Or some other regular $n$-gon.) From one of its vertex we sent a foton to one of its neighbour vertices. The foton will then infinitely remain on the sides of the square... Please adapt the question or except this counterexample... Also, please make clear what does it mean "after infinite reflections". For instance, we may look at the sequence of the slopes of the rays, and some convergence seems to be expected in the long run. In the "generic case". The OP has to tell us what is generic for E.

Comment: By "infinite reflections", I mean the sequence of slopes of the ray will converge to 0. 
The ray must pass through a focus at some point. (I forgot to mention this in the question earlier, edited now.)

Comment: The rays do not need to pass through the focal points, again, counterexample square 1-2-3-4-1-... (inside a circle), or pentagonal path 1-2-3-4-5-1... or 1-3-5-2-4-1... and the rays do not get close to the center of the circle.

Comment: No no; you misunderstood the question; a focal ray i.e. only a ray passing through a focus will converge after 'infinite reflections'; not just any ray.

Comment: Oh, thanks, my fault! In this case, let $F_1, F_2$ be the foci of the ellipse, $(\pm c,0)$. The perpendiculars in them on their line, $x=\pm c$, are delimiting four regions, let us call them "left, up, right, down", and it seems that after some few steps the rays reflect in points $(x_n,y_n)$ that are either left or right. Then, after this left-right-stabilization, a picture seems to make $|y_n|\to 0$ by geometrical reasons... In this second it seems for me ok, if ok, than this idea should be convertible to a proof....

Comment: Hmm, isn't it the case that a focal ray, after being reflected, will pass through the other focus, and continue as a _new_ focal ray? Then the claim of convergence would seem to be at odds with the fact reflections work the same in the other direction. If we reverse a path that converges to the major axis we get one that _diverges_ from it.

Comment: @Henning You're assuming that the ray aligns with the major axis after some finite time (only then can you use the backtracking argument). 'Ray converges to the major axis after infinite reflections' would mean that the ray becomes 'arbitrarily closely aligned with the major axis' as the number of reflections increases and it's limit is the major axis.

Comment: This is theorem 2.8 on page 10 here: https://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2014/REUPapers/Park.pdf